# Failed to load class "org.jboss.as.capedwarf.api.Logger" for handler "CAPEDWARF"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openshift, capedwarf

I'm getting this error from the JBoss logs when trying to run my GAE app with Openshift/Capedwarf:

```
Removing existing logging.properties
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/jbossas
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.7.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -client -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=115m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.node.name=app-gwtgae.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.13.25.1 -Djboss.server.data.dir=/var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/app-root/data/jboss-as7 -Dcom.google.appengine.runtime.environment=Production -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.net.MAX_THREADS=20
=========================================================================
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load class "org.jboss.as.capedwarf.api.Logger" for handler "CAPEDWARF"
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.HandlerConfigurationImpl.<init>(HandlerConfigurationImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.addHandlerConfiguration(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyConfigurator.java:606)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureLogger(PropertyConfigurator.java:541)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:480)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:96)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.configure(ConfigurationPersistence.java:128)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:300)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:262)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:312)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:310)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:310)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:265)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1430)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1428)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.capedwarf.api.Logger from [Module "org.jboss.as.capedwarf:main" from local module loader @1bd56d0 (roots: /var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/config/modules,/var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/app-root/runtime/capedwarf/capedwarf-modules/jboss-as7-modules,/var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/jbossas/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:73)
    ... 21 more
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/jbossas
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=12c481204382ec16dc0003b3 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.node.name=app-gwtgae.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.13.25.1 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
Declared property enabled wasn't found on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/jbossas
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=12c481204382ec16dc0003b3 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.node.name=app-gwtgae.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.13.25.1 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
Declared property enabled wasn't found on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/jbossas
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=12c481204382ec16dc0003b3 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.node.name=app-gwtgae.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.13.25.1 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
Declared property enabled wasn't found on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/12c481204382ec16dc0003b3/jbossas
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=12c481204382ec16dc0003b3 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.node.name=app-gwtgae.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.13.25.1 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
Declared property enabled wasn't found on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
```

Initially, the template capedwarf app worked fine, but when I 'git push' my app its not working. I can assure that the same git repo worked fine as Cloudbees deploys this app with jenkins to GAE cloud (appspot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this with the latest release, but locally?